# How do you change the text highlight marker in react native?

Tags: react-native

[SearchBar with input text higlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bue5r.pngA) It is possible to change the color of the text highlight marker in reactnative?  From The {TexInput} core component Probs, {selectionColor} allows for cursor and highlight color customization but not highlight marker.

Answer (score 0):

On Android and by default, this color comes from the app's theme, defined in *android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml* under the name `colorAccent`:

```xml
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

The value of the color is defined in *android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml*. Changing the value will change the accent color of the app, which will in turn be applied to the text highlight marker.

Comment: Thank you! but this is possible for android native dev, not for reactnative.

Comment: @ChukwuSmart React Native apps are native apps that include React Native as a dependency. The resulting Android app is available under the _android_ directory in the root directory of your React Native project, and, unless you are using Expo without ejecting, is fully editable and configurable.
Just don't forget to rebuild the app after editing the color resources.

Comment: Thanks alot. I also found the Expo guilds on **Adding custom native code** helpful. [link](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/)